# Prime divisors of the respectively minimal binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

In view of Chebyshev's approach to prime numbers, I would like to ask about the regularities and peculiarities of the two sequences $\ \beta(n)\ $ and $\ \gamma(n),\ $ which I define as follows:

- $\ \beta(n)\ $ is the smallest integer $\ b\ $ such that $\ \binom bn\ $ has at least $\ n\ $ different prime divisors;
- $\ \gamma(n)\ $ is the smallest integer $\ c\ $ such that $\ \binom cn\ $ has at least $\ n\ $ different prime divisors $\ p\gt n$.

Of course it would be nice (but not realistic?) to compute these two sequences or give a sharp estimate. Even not so sharp bounds but with explicit scope of application like *for every* $\ n\ge 720\ $ *(or whatever the constant)* rather than *for almost all...* would be still interesting, I'd think, and possibly can find some applications (say, combinatorial).

The properties under the consideration can be monotonicity of the sequences $\ \beta\ $ and $\ \gamma\ $ (including the deviations from the monotonicity); also the frequency of occurrences of prime numbers as $\ \beta(n)\ $ or $\ \gamma(n)\ $ respectively. Would they be more common in $\ \gamma\ $ then in $\ \beta\,$?

Comment: You should also consider B(n) and G(n), which are the smallest values of b and g such that for all c >= b or h >= g, one has c choose n have at least n different prime divisors or h choose n have at least n different prime divisors greater than n.  Stoermer's Theorem suggests to me that these values also exist.  Gerhard "Wants Really Explicit Application Scope" Paseman, 2014.10.01

Comment: @Gerhard, if you believe in the infinitude of Mersenne primes then the respective B(n) G(n) are not defined for  $\infty$-many n. Perhaps there would be many other probable examples of B G not defined.

Comment: (@Gerhard, there is more than one $\LaTeX$ way to write binomial coefficients. But once I learned \binom my life became easier, e.g. \binom {12}2 $\ = \binom {12}2$).

Comment: Wlod, I only see that Mersenne primes prevent the definability of G(2).  Indeed, I believe one can prove B(2)=4 and I think it is not hard to show B(3) and G(3) exist and are larger than 8, but not by much.  Gerhard "Or We're On Different Pages" Paseman, 2014.10.03

Comment: @Gerhard, you're right, of course, that possible infinitude of Mersenne primes potentially precludes G(2), and not more (I was chaotic in my comment). I'd write a program but others have a much better computing environment (mine is poor). Gerhard, you could take your comment to formulate your own MO Question, I'd welcome it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just consider the second of the two problems posed.  Changing notation slightly, it asks for the least natural number $n=n(k)$ such that  $(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+k)$ is divisible by $k$ primes all larger than $k$.  First I claim that $n(k) \le Ck^{e}$ for some constant $C$.  To see this note that 
 $$ 
 \sum_{n\le N} \sum_{p>k, p|(n+1)\cdots (n+k)} 1 = \sum_{k<p\le N} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{n\le N, p|(n+j)} 1 = 
 \sum_{k< p \le N} k \Big( \frac{N}{p} +O(1)\Big), 
 $$ 
 and using $\sum_{p\le x} 1/p = \log \log x + B + O(1/\log x)$ this is 
 $$
 = kN \log \frac{\log N}{\log k} + O\Big(\frac{N}{\log k}\Big).
 $$ 
 If $N >C k^e$ for some large $C$ then this exceeds $kN$, and we deduce that there is some $n \le N$ with $(n+1)\cdots (n+k)$  containing $k$ primes all larger than $k$.  This easy argument may be found in Theorem 3.3 (part 3) of [Erdos and Turk](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1984-17.pdf).

My guess would be that $n(k) \ge k^{e-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon >0$, but this seems difficult to show.  One can see easily that $n(k) \ge c k^2$ for some small positive constant $c$.  To prove this, note that if $n\le k^2-k$ then each $n+j$ (with $1\le j\le k$) can have at most one prime factor larger than $k$.  So if we can show that there are integers in $[n,n+k]$ that are $k$-smooth (all prime factors below $k$) then clearly $(n+1)\cdots (n+k)$ cannot be divisible by $k$ primes larger $k$.  Choose $r=\lceil \sqrt{n+k}\rceil$ and $s = \lceil \sqrt{r^2 - (n+k)}\rceil$.  Then $r^2-s^2$ can be checked to be in $[n,n+k]$ (if $n\le ck^4$ for a suitable $c$), and $r^2-s^2=(r+s)(r-s)$ is clearly $(r+s)$-smooth.  This shows that if $n\le ck^2$ then the interval $[n,n+k]$ will contain $k$-smooth numbers.  (In fact, it shows that the interval $[x,x+cx^{1/4}]$ contains $\sqrt{x}$-smooth numbers.)  Erdos and Turk (see Theorem 3.3 part 1) showed that $n(k) \ge k^{2+\delta}$ for some small $\delta>0$, and this remains the best known.

To show why the problem of getting lower bounds for $n(k)$ is difficult, let me isolate a consequence 
 which is not yet known.  If the bound $n(k) \ge k^A$ holds for all large $k$, then every interval 
 $[x,x+x^{1/A}]$ must contain a $x^{1/A}$-smooth number.  This consequence is only known for $A<2.5$; this follows from the argument involving $r^2-s^2$ given above, and was noted in a paper of [Friedlander and Lagarias](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/short.pdf) (which appeared in J Number Theory).   So proving the expected lower bound of $n(k) \ge k^{e-\epsilon}$ would have interesting, as yet unknown, consequences.

Comment: Suppose I gave you the k primes (and, strangely, asked only for odd k).  Other than that 2n was smaller than the product of the k primes, could you tell me how small n could be so that each of n+1,..,n+k was divisible by exactly one of those primes?  Failing that, can you give bounds on n if the product (n+1)...(n+k) isnonzero and is divisible by the product of the k given primes?

Comment: Thank you a lot. @Lucia, I enjoyed your answer. To follow the calculations I'd like to ask a volunteer (you?--I don't dare :-), if possible, to translate the common number-theoretical notation into set-theoretical way. I am talking about the style translation along the line: $\ \sum_{x\in A} 1 = |A|.\ $ Or, say, $\ \sum_{1\le k\le n,\ k\cdot n\le M} 1\ =\  \left|\{(k\ n)\in \mathbb N^2:k\cdot n\le M\ \ and\ \ k\le n\}\right|.\ $ And if I see $\ \sum_{k\ n\ge 1,\ k\cdot n\le M} 1\ $ then I am lost, I don't know how to read it uniquely.

Comment: The number theoretical 1-summation formulas perhaps are compact but in my case they lead to strain on my eyes. Also, non-specialists especially may occasionally get confused when it is hard or impossible to decode the 1-notation formula.